# Tratamento de unidades de medida no banco de dados

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql

Em um projeto vou ter unidades de medida grama/unidade/litro. Não que um produto eu posso vender ele por grama e litro, se entrou 10kg de carne vou dar saída de 10kg de carne como devo tratá-lo? Devo por no banco somente código?

Comment: Rangel, meu forte não é BD, porém dependerá do nível de granularidade que você deseja. No caso real, geralmente, podemos comprar 100g gramas de carne ne? então em vez de colocar kg em kg, creio que uma granularidade de grama seria boa.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Geralmente você normaliza o dado. O dado obtido (entrada) ou apresentado (saída) pode ser na unidade de grandeza que quiser, você então converte para uma grandeza específica que está no banco de dados, o mesmo vale para o tipo de medida, embora quase sempre é estranho comprar por um tipo de unidade e vender por outro (acontece, mas é raro, quase sempre é um erro, em exemplos artificiais tem grande chance de ser um erro de avaliação), mas parece que você não tem esse problema.

As pessoas tem dificuldade de entender o que é entrada de dado, saída de dado e o dado em si. Se preocupe com o dado e como converter entradas e saídas para o dado de um jeito padrão. Entrada e saída serve para um humano lidar. A matemática existe por si própria independe do que o humano entende. Os objetos também. O computador lida de um jeito diferente, deixe ele fazer o trabalho dele do jeito mais simples e normal possível.

Vou usar o peso como exemplo. Alguns produtos podem exigir que a menor unidade seja miligrama ou até algo menor que isto, mas são mais raros. Só evite ter o dado com parte fracionária, sempre que possível mantenha o dado de forma inteira. Então se puder ter 27,6 gramas é melhor guardar o dado em miligramas. Se apenas um produto no banco de dados puder ter gramas fracionadas então o correto seria usar miligramas (claro que pode usar decigramas ou centigramas, mas pra que complicar?). Mas provavelmente gramas está bom para seu caso.

Então se o dado for entrada em quilogramas e no banco de dados você armazena como gramas você deve multiplicar esse número por 1000 antes de armazenar o dado sem si. Quando pegar o dado do banco de dados e for usar em algum contexto que seja de quilogramas você deve dividir por 1000 para ter do jeito que deseja naquele caso.

Cada produto pode ter uma unidade, isso não importa muito para o banco de dados, desde que mantenha uma forma padronizada. Claro que a aplicação terá que fazer o uso de acordo com o tipo de unidade usada. Então terá uma coluna dizendo qual é o tipo de unidade usada naquele produto. A aplicação pegará isto e decidirá como converter, apresentar e manipular esse dado de acordo com a unidade usada.